# How much protein i really need per day for muscle gain with moderate workout

Tags: protein

I started to workout in gym

Age : 27, Male

Height : 6.1 [184 ]

Weight : **68** kgs [ **150** pound]

[ Lightly active (moderate exercise but sedentary job)]

usually i eat 50gms/110 pounds of protein per day , According to [this link](https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/calpro.htm) , if i want muscle gain, i need **179 Gm/393 pound** protein , OMG is that much protein really required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1 gram of protein* per *1 pound of muscle mass* is a good rule of thumb if you want your muscles to grow.

If you weight 150-lbs and you are at 15% body fat, then you have around 120 pounds of muscle mass (throwing the last digits out as bone mass).

If you can distribute about 120 grams of protein throughout your day, then your body should have a good protein supply for building new muscle tissue.

Half of a skinless chicken breast is about 6-ounces. The fitness app on my phone shows that comes to 50 grams of protein. Similarly, 6-ounces of Pacific Whiting fish comes to 31 grams of protein. There is 81 grams of protein.

You still need carbohydrates and fat in your diet.

You are not alone in finding it difficult to get your protein requirements, though. That is why the supplement industry provides so many protein drinks.